# Aligned data: speed dependance on relative sampling size vs sampling frequency on a constant data read

Tags: c++, performance, memory-alignment

I have a 30MB array of bytes stored in a memory buffer. I want to sample 10% of the array in a periodic fashion.

I can sample every 10th byte:

> xoooooooooxoooooooooxoooooooooxoooooooooxoooooooooxooooooooox...

Or I can sample 4 bytes at a time, every 40 bytes:

> xxxxooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooxxxxoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo...

In other words, I an arbitrary amount of bytes I read at a time, provided that the analyzed bytes amount to 10% of my total data, and that my reads are evenly sized and spaced.

How does the performance of reading this data depend on the sampling structure size, provided I use no vectorized instructions like SSE?

How does the speed tend to differ between x86 and ARM?

Is there a drawing line (say: 32 bytes+) after which increasing the size of the sampling structure does not improve performance more than a few percent?

Given that the total data will not fit in the cache, does varying the sampling structure size change the performance substantially at all?

Comment: Clarify *reading*.  Are you reading from a file or from a buffer in memory?  Are you reading from a port?

Comment: From a signal processing point of view, those two a completely different sampling schemes.

Comment: Can you sample every 16 bytes or 32 bytes instead of 10 and 40?

Comment: I would think the scheme which has the most bytes together (the second) has better cache locality. The only way to know is to time it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews reading from a buffer in memory.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I can read 16 or 32 or any other arbitrary number of bytes at a time.

Comment: Then why not read it linearly?

Comment: @NeilKirk there is a performance vs quality consideration that I must make (and this question addresses the performance curve); the quality of my system does depend on the sampling size so it may not be effective to just read the first 10% of the data array.

Comment: I just did a little repo (using my own timer object) and got 0.163895s for 4 every 40 and 0.217687s for 1 every 10.  With release build I got: 0.00224358s and 0.00227313s which is really too small to notice any difference.  30mb isn't all that much data to be honest.

Answer (score 4):

When reading 10% of data from a very long array of bytes on hardware with cache line of size `L` you will get maximum performance when your reads start at an alignment of a cache line, read `L` bytes at a time, skip the following `9*L` bytes, and continue from that point on. This maximizes the number of cache hits, speeding up your program, because you load only 1/10th of your data into cache.

With cache line sizes on the order of 64 bytes, this leaves pretty large gaps in your sample, so you will end up using an approach that reads fewer bytes at a time.

Let's look at the two approaches that you have, i.e. 4 bytes at a time vs. one byte at a time. Let's assume that L=64.

The first approach will have six to seven hits cache line, depending on how far inside the line the first read "lands". If the first read is within the initial four bytes, you get six hits; otherwise, you get five hits. On average, you will have 6.4 hits per cache line (The math is as follows: four "good" positions give us six hits, and six "bad" positions give us five hits; divide by the total number of possible initial positions (4*7+6*6)/10).

The second approach will give you four to eight hits per cache line - again, depending on the placement of the first read. Assuming that all reads are aligned at 4-byte boundaries, starting a read at positions 0 through 20, inclusive, will give you eight hits per line. Starting a read at other positions will give you four hits per line. You have six "good" positions (0, 4, 8, 12, 16, and 20) and four "bad" positions (24, 28, 32, and 36), so the result is again 6.4, or (8*6+4*4)/10.

As you can see, there is no difference in cache utilization between the two approaches. This makes sense, because you never skip a line. You would be able to make an improvement only if you could skip over an entire cache line worth of memory.

Again, assuming that the size of cache line is 64 and that you read 10% of data, the smallest whole number of bytes you need to read at a time is 7 bytes of every 70 (or more likely 8 of every 80, because 8 is more "alignment-friendly" number).

Comment: Cache line counting seems quite accurate as a predictor to performance at a first glance as per Robinson's comment; if so, this would be great for making estimates of my algorithm's performance with more degrees of freedom (such as: read a total 1% instead of 10% of the data).

Comment: I don't get your "cache hit" point. Whether it is every 10 or 40, every byte of the 30MB will be loaded into the cache, so the worst will be two more cache line at the start and at the end of the 30MB.

Comment: @ElderBug You are absolutely right, I completely screwed up my math, and I did it twice! The first case has 6 or 7 hits, not 5 or 6. The second case has 10 possibilities, not 64. Once the math is fixed, the results become identical, as they should be (your explanation of why is a lot shorter, though :-) I edited to fix the math and explain the minimum read size OP needs to use to get an improvement in cache performance. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BoykoPerfanov I will add that since you are only processing 10%, only the memory bandwidth will be significant (and the number of cache lines loaded, if you can afford spacing by 64 bytes or more). Mem bandwidth will typically be 10GB/s, or 20GB/s for dual channel (two RAM sticks), thus capping your performance for 30MB at 2.9ms, and 1.5ms for dual channel.

Answer (score 1):

This is too broad to answer, but I will give some suggestions.

### Sampling From A Port

In general, sampling from a port is more timing related than memory related.  For example, we read an ADC every 1ms, using an ISR.  The data is stored into an array and then sent to a smoothing algorithm.

### Sampling A File

The best method to sample from a file is to haul as much data into a buffer as possible, then sample from the buffer.

Sampling, one byte out of every N bytes is like reading a 2D matrix.  The processor uses a pointer and an offset (10 in your case).  This load is usually one instruction. So the loop increments the pointer by 10.  If the data can't fit into the cache, the processor would reload the cache.  If you can design the period to be a multiple of the cache line size, your program would perform faster.

Your biggest bottleneck is reading from the file.  The optimal method for reading from a file is to read the most data with fewest requests.  Also keep the hard drive spinning.  The overhead of starting up a stopped drive is high compared to keeping the drive spinning.

### Other Methods

You may be able to use DMA to read the file and interrupt the processor after a given number of bytes have been read.

Multi-threading may help with reading from files.

### Performance

Performance depends on profiling (i.e. measuring).  As far as the difference between an ARM and x86, you will have to measure.  The variance will be great due to the different clock rates going into the processor and how the processor is configured to use the clock rate.

**The only way to truly answer a performance question is to get data by profiling and analyzing the data.**